# WP common.phar no such file

Tags: wordpress, phar

I run wp plugin on my localhost, it uses Common.phar file in config, and it returns the error: Warning: require_once(/usr/share/php/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
But on my localhost (used Apache), there is no such path. How to activate and run a plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only problem, you can create the path and file manually. But I guess you can also provide Wordpress an option to log things into another file